# Extracting order of client server from a dictionary using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sequence

I have a dictionary like below which for example, for the first item means 5 is the customer of 2. and in the last item, as you can see, 2 is the customer of 4 and  4 is also the customer of item 3.

```
customer_provider_dic= {'2':['5'],'1':['2'],'3':['4'],'4':['2']}
```

I am trying to extract all chains of customer of these items. The output will be like this:

```
[2,5]
[1,2,5]
[3,4,2,5]
[4,2,5]
```

I really confused how can I extracts these chains. Any suggestion for the flowchart or the steps I should follow.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct output? Because `[2,5]` and `[3,4]` are clearly going from server to customer, but `[1,2,4,3]` is going the opposite direction, and `[4,2,1]` seems to be reversing direction in the middle. So, if that _is_ the right output, you're going to have to explain what "chain" means here, because it's not obvious.

Comment: Why do you have [1,2,4,3]  ??

Comment: You need to implement topological sort to get what you are looking for.

Comment: you are right. I will edit my question. thank you

Comment: Why are the dict values lists? Will there ever be more than 1 item in those lists?

Comment: @PM2Ring yes the value of lists could be more than one item. I will edit the title of my question too. Excuse me for my bad English.

Comment: Ok. In that case the solution is a bit more complex, since multiple list items means that there will be branching chains. BTW, the last line of your output `[4,2,3]` isn't correct.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes it is a little complex. I am thinking about an algorithm for it since today morning until now:( but nothing. Can you please help me:) I really have confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, here's a solution that works if all the lists contain exactly one item.

```
def simple_chain(graph, key):
    chain = [key]
    while True:
        lst = graph.get(key)
        if lst is None:
            # There's nothing left to add to the chain
            break
        key = lst[0]
        if key in chain:
            # We've found a loop
            break
        chain.append(key)
    return chain

customer_provider = {
    '2': ['5'], '1': ['2'], '3': ['4'], '4': ['2'],
}

data = customer_provider
for k in data:
    print(simple_chain(data, k))
```

**output**

```
['2', '5']
['1', '2', '5']
['3', '4', '2', '5']
['4', '2', '5']
```

---

The general solution is a little harder. We can create all the chains using a recursive generator. The code below works, but it's not very efficient, since it makes the same sub-chains multiple times.

The basic strategy is similar to the previous version, but we need to loop over all the keys in each list, and make a new chain for each one.

To fully understand how this code works you need to be familiar with [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) and with Python [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators). You may also find this page helpful: [Understanding Generators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1756096/4014959); there are also various Python generators tutorials available online.

```
def make_chains(graph, key, chain):
    ''' Generate all chains in graph that start at key.
        Stop a chain when graph[key] doesn't exist, or if
        a loop is encountered.
    '''
    lst = graph.get(key)
    if lst is None:
        yield chain
        return
    for k in lst:
        if k in chain:
            # End this chain here because there's a loop
            yield chain
        else:
            # Add k to the end of this chain and
            # recurse to continue the chain
            yield from make_chains(graph, k, chain + [k])

customer_provider = {
    '2': ['5'], '1': ['2'], '3': ['4'], '4': ['2'],
}

pm_data = {
    '2': ['5'], '1': ['2'], '3': ['4', '6'], 
    '4': ['2'], '6': ['1', '5'],
}

#data = customer_provider
data = pm_data

for k in data:
    for chain in make_chains(data, k, [k]):
        print(chain)
```

If we run that code with `data = customer_provider` it produces the same output as the previous version. Here's the output when run with `data = pm_data`.

```
['2', '5']
['1', '2', '5']
['3', '4', '2', '5']
['3', '6', '1', '2', '5']
['3', '6', '5']
['4', '2', '5']
['6', '1', '2', '5']
['6', '5']
```

---

The `yield from` syntax is a Python 3 feature. To run this code on Python 2, change

```
yield from make_chains(graph, k, chain + [k])
```

to

```
for ch in make_chains(graph, k, chain + [k]):
    yield ch
```

Prior to Python 3.6 `dict` does not retain the insertion order of keys, so `for k in data` can loop over the keys of `data` in any order. The output lists will still be correct, though. You may wish to replace that loop with

```
for k in sorted(data):
```

to get the chains in order.

Comment: thank you for your answer. the simple_chain function is fine, I tried to use make_chains function, I am getting this error
yield from make_chains(graph, k, chain + [k])
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @ShahroozPooryousef I guess you're still using Python 2, since `yield from` only works in Python 3. But it's very easy to adapt that code to Python 2, I'll update my answer in a few minutes.